# I have another app (not nginx) running on localhost. How do I setup nginx so it runs on a different local IP?

Tags: nginx

I have an application that is not nginx running on localhost. I want to setup a server on nginx but one that isn't running on localhost so I can use them simultaneously.

My `/etc/hosts` file would ideally look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1    a.website.loc
127.0.0.2 another.website.loc
```

`127.0.0.1` is the route running on an app that is not nginx.

`127.0.0.2` is the route I want nginx running on.

My nginx.conf would ideally look something like this:

```
server {
    # listen ???;
    server_name another.website.loc;
    root /path/to/another_website;
}
```

So how do I set this up on nginx? Or would I set it up on localhost too but running on a different port?

Thanks! PS I am running on a macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

To listen another IP you should have another network card with the other IP.

But you have to options:

1. Modify your OS hosts file to assign another name to your server, and then on nginx

   ```
   server {
       server_name yournameonhostsfile
   ```
2. use another port (as you stated on your question):

   ```
   server {
       listen 8000;
   ```